# How to create (or use the existing) database on an SQL 2017 deployed via Azure VM?

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machines, database, azure-sql

Please note the question is about the SQL 2017 that comes inside an Azure VM, not the Azure Databases.

Basically, I deployed an Azure VM with SQL 2017 Enterprise installed on it already, by MS.

Now, I want to create some test tables, populate data and play with SQL Server 2016.

However, I don't know if I have:
 - Database instance
 - Database user
 - Master table
 - Other things necessary to kick off an SQLS DB

Any directions, please?

Comment: connect to the VM, run management studio and login to localhost:1433?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure VM with SQLS comes with a ready instance and system database.

I had the "SQL Authentication" disabled and windows authentication doesn't work right out of the box.

To log into the database: Enable SQL authentication and provide a username and password (and port).
Provide these for login.

The system database owner will be your SQL auth user concatanated with 'sql'. EG: dbUser -> dbUsersql